# Split string based on a recurring pattern

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I have the following sting:

```
a='text1fig [1]text2fig [15]text3fig [234]text4fig [2234]text5'
```

I want to split it to:

```
texts=['text1','text2','text3','text4','text5']
```

I tried:

```
import re    
texts=re.split('fig \\[[0-3000]\\]',texts) .
```

but it doesn't work.
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number ranges don't work like that. Just use `\d` instead. Additionally, you'll want a single backslash, as a double backslash is taken to be a literal backslash (you want it to escape the `[`/`]` metachars instead).

```
text = re.split(r'fig\s*\[\d+\]', a)

print(text)
['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4', 'text5']
```

---

**Regex Details**

```
fig   
\s*   # 0 or more whitespace chars 
\[    # literal opening brace
\d+   # 1 or more digits
\]    # literal closing brace
```

Comment: what is the function of r in r'fig...' it seems to work without it as well. thanks

Comment: @user552231 Raw string literal. It's good practice to include it.

Comment: alternatively, `re.findall` with the pattern `text\d+`.

Comment: @timgeb Assuming the text is actually textX.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use "re.findall" instead of "re.split"

```
texts = re.findall('text\d', a)

['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4', 'text5']
```

Comment: Besides the fact that you copied this from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240200/split-string-using-regularity-in-python/46240223?noredirect=1#comment79444809_46240223, it's also a bad idea, you don't expect to see an actual use case with text1, text2, and so on. That's just an example.

Comment: Just wanted to add that if you use that it only works if you have 1 digit after text. However, if you have more than 1 digit, you should use 'text\d+

Comment: You're right Sam, the "+" would be appropriate if the numbering scheme went past 9. Well it isn't copied COLDSPEED, so there's that...and it satisfies the question, nowhere does it say that it is just an example.